# Limit of a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Consider a positive real sequence $\{\varepsilon_n\}$ that monotonically decreases to zero, and a finite $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I learnt the following during a foundational probability class, but I am not sure why is $A_2$ open at $x$. How to explain this?
$$A_1 = \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (-\infty,x+\varepsilon_i] = (-\infty,x]$$
$$A_2 = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (-\infty,x-\varepsilon_i] = (-\infty,x)$$

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in A_2$, then $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty(-\infty,x-\varepsilon_i]$, and therefore $x\in(-\infty,x-\varepsilon_i]$ for some $i\in\mathbb{N}$. But this is false.

Comment: so if the sequnce converges to some value $a$, then there does not exist any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $\varepsilon_n = a$?

Comment: Which sequence? What is that $a$?

Comment: sequence in the question, and $a = 0$; say $\varepsilon_n = 0, \forall n\geq N_0\in\mathbb{N}$, then how does the statement hold true?

Comment: How can you have $\varepsilon_n=0$ for each $n$? Didn't you write that the sequence is monotonically decreasing?

Comment: did not add the word "strictly", though

Comment: Right. But then the statement is false.

Comment: The preamble says "positive real sequence"

Comment: oh right! thanks